how to write it properly? FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY 'n'
How to write this line properly?
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY 'n'

or set it to a variable?
select * from employee into outfile "/var/lib/mysql-files/data.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY 'n';

This is working. But
set @Cbatch_no = "data";
set @outfile = concat("/var/lib/mysql-files/",@cbatch_no,".csv");
select * from employee into outfile @outfile
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY 'n';

Not working.

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@outfile  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY 'n'' at line 1.

Please help..
